# QPixmap not working with image path stored in variable

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qpixmap

when I write the image path directly like this

```
QPixmap imgBtry("/some/path/resources/Battery100.png");
```

it works perfectly but its not working when i store the path in a variable. What should i do? Following is the complete code.

```
//global variables
std::string path;
std::string img100 = "/some/path/resources/Battery100.png";
std::string img75 = "/some/path/resources/Battery75.png";
std::string img50 = "/some/path/resources/Battery50.png";
std::string img25 = "/some/path/resources/Battery25.png";

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPixmap imgBtry(img50);
    ui->label_2->setPixmap(imgBtry.scaled(50,50,Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,Qt::FastTransformation));
}
```

Comment: Does that code actually compile?  Try changing `std::string` to `QString`.

Comment: Seconding the recommendation to use `QString` - all Qt functions that take strings use `QString`. There is really no need to prefer `std::string` since there are no advantages over using it.

Comment: thanks a lot, changing it to QString helped.

Comment: Why are you even using `std::string` when you have the wonderful `QString` available?

Comment: @KubaOber I am new to C++ and QT i didn't know about Qstring thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What error do you get? A guess could be:

The QPixmap constructor takes a QString as argument. It works when you put the string directly because it is a c-string (char *) and QString have an constructor taking an c-string as input. But have no constructor taking a std::string as input.

So either:

1) define your strings as c-strings.

or

2) convert your std::strings to c-strings before calling QPixmap:

```
QPixmap imgBtry(img50.c_str());
```

Comment: changing the variable to a QString worked thanks for the help

Comment: `QString::fromStdString` is the right way to go, not using `c_str`!

Comment: You are right, the best solution is to use QString.